# Event handler getting selected tab text throws error in background update thread

Tags: c#, user-interface, thread-safety

I'm currently building a c# scheduling application and I just can't seem to wrap my mind around why this piece of code:

```
    private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           currWCLabel.Text = workOrderTabbing.SelectedTab.Text;
    }
```

causes this piece of code to crash at "workOrderTabbing.Invoke(d, new object[] { });" line?

> error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..)

```
    private void clearDGVTextSafe()
    {
        if (workOrderTabbing.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new safeClearDGVDelgate(clearDGVTextSafe);
            workOrderTabbing.Invoke(d, new object[] { });
        }
        else
        {
            workOrderTabbing.TabPages.Clear(); ;
        }      
    }
```

This above code is called by the background thread to clear the schedule before repainting it.
In my mind, these two should be completely separate? If I change the text line to "currWCLabel.Text = "blah blah blah";" everything works fine?

Comment: Add a try-catch block and take a look at the exception at runtime. `'System.NullReferenceException'` is a pretty generic error message (in that it leaves some room to track down), so it's not as easy to infer without more details.

Comment: @Dortimer okay now im even more confused... i put a try catch on it with the catch just being "            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }" and it works now???????

Comment: @Dortimer it is clearing the form right and everything, it's not like its skipping the clear?

Comment: So, adding that try-catch block will stop the program from crashing, but it doesn't fix the error. Set a breakpoint in that catch block, and you can view what's in `e` during runtime.

Comment: @Dortimer i have a breakpoint at the exception and it doesn't stop, it is working perfectly now? im so confused how did the try catch fix it??

Comment: Interesting. If you want, remove the try-catch block, and set a breakpoint on that function. If you step through the code (`F10`), it'll hit the exception and you can see the details that way too.

Comment: @Dortimer please excuse my stupidity, i didn't have my breakpoint on the "{":D with "exception e" it is  null when i hover over in debug. Should i use a different exception?

Comment: @Dortimer okay here's the exception, Object reference not set to an instance of an object., and it says the  target site is "incomingWorkView.Form1.TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object, System.EventArgs)" why is it even messing with this in the clear dvg area? is the first one taking a hold of the tab control and not releasing it or something?

Comment: @Dortimer ahhhhh ive figured it out! when the dvg clears, there are no tabs but the tab index has changed, the event handler then tries to pick tab -1 and then throws an exception! thanks for being with my in my time of peril:D

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here was the problem, when the background thread clears, there are no tabs but the tab index has changed.Then the event handler tries to pick tab -1 and throws an exception!

here was the check that was needed:

```
        if(workOrderTabbing.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            currWCLabel.Text = workOrderTabbing.SelectedTab.Text;
        }
```